# How to TryParseExact a string containing just the 24-based hour?

Tags: .net, exception, datetime

It just doesn't want to work:

```
DateTime time;

DateTime.TryParseExact("17", "HH", ..., out time);
  // works fine

DateTime.TryParseExact("9", "HH", ..., out time);
  // works fine, but 9 doesn't match HH (nor should it)

DateTime.TryParseExact("9:", "H':'", ..., out time);
  // works fine

DateTime.TryParseExact("9", "H", ..., out time);
  // exception: "Input string was not in a correct format"
```

The fact that #3 works offers an obvious work-around, but it's one of those things that would make me go "WTF" if I saw it in someone else's code. Is `TryParseExact` buggy or something?

Comment: Maybe it makes more sense to convert it to TimeSpan instead of DateTime...

Comment: @Francisco I don't think so; `TimeSpan` doesn't parse things like "am/pm" because it represents a time _span_, rather than a point in time. And you never have things like "it took us 2.5 am hours".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.TryParseExact("5", "%H", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out time)`.

To parse the hour in a 24-hour clock without leading zero one could be tempted to use just the `"H"` format, but a [custom date and time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) must consist of two or more characters, which would lead to `"H"` being interpreted as a [standard date and time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx), resulting in a format exception.

From [MSDN on Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

> To use any of the custom date and time format specifiers as the only
>   specifier in a format string (that is, to use the "d", "f", "F", "g",
>   "h", "H", "K", "m", "M", "s", "t", "y", "z", ":", or "/" custom format
>   specifier by itself), include a space before or after the specifier,
>   or include a percent ("%") format specifier before the single custom
>   date and time specifier.

I prefer to include the `%` sign before since I find that a space before or after may be interpreted as a typing mistake and be removed by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

What about using it like this:

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact("09", "HH", null, 
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

Comment: The "9" is user input; I can't just ask them to enter the 0.

Comment: You could prepend the 0 if the string length is 1. Anyway, João Angelo's answer works beautifully.